# How to fill the rest of line with space() / string()?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am generating a word document filled with user inputed values (userform input).

Is there any way to fill the space after typed value with amount of whitespace required to fill the rest of the line?

Or how to get the amount of characters left to the end of line?

Comment: Unless you are working with fixed space fonts just adding whitespace may not work. Have you considered using a table. In VBA, add a table, add a row, address the cells to load the data. Repeat last two for the rest of the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. This would likely help you anyway.

If you have a `String` `a`, which you want to pad with blanks up to 255 characters, you would do

```
Dim apad As String
apad = a & space(255 - len(a))  ' or
'apad = a & String(255 - len(a), " ")  ' or
'apad = a & WorksheetFunction.Rept(" ", 255 - len(a))
```

You then use `apad` for whatever you need.